# $p,q$ odd primes, $q\mid a^p-1\Rightarrow q\mid a-1$ or $\,2p\mid q-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $p$ and $q$ are odd primes and $q$ can divide $a^p-1$, then either $q$ divides $a-1$ or else $q=2kp+1$ for some integer $k$.

I thought the supposition is $a\equiv 1 (mod\ q)$.
So $$(a-1)(a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}+...+1) \equiv 0 (mod\ q)$$
Then I proved $q$ may divide $a-1$.
But I don't know how to check that $q=2kp+1$.
thks

Answer (score 2):

If $q$ is an odd prime, divisor of $a^p-1$, then $a^p \equiv 1$ (mod $q$). Therefore the possible orders of $a$ modulo $q$ are $1$ or $p$.

If it is $1$, then $a\equiv1$ (mod $q$) $\Rightarrow q|(a-1)$.

If it is $p$, then $a^p\equiv1$ (mod $q$). Notice that gcd$(a, q)=1$. In fact, if for some $c$ integer, $c|a$ and $c|q$, we'll have to: 
$$c|a \Rightarrow c|a^p$$ $$c|q \,, q|(a^p-1) \Rightarrow c|(a^p-1)$$ $$c|a^p \,, c|(a^p-1) \Rightarrow c|[a^p - (a^p - 1)]=1$$

Therefore, according to Euler's theorem: $a^{\varphi(q)}=a^{q-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $q$). Since $p$ in this case is the order of $a$ modulo $q$ then $p|(q-1)$. Since $2|(q-1)$ and gcd$(2, p)=1$ then $2p|(q-1)$.

Where $q=2pk+1$, for some $k$ integer.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis is that $[a]^{p} = [1]$, where $[x]$ denote the class of the integer $x$ in the multiplicative group $G$ of invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$. This group has $q-1$ elements.

If $q$ does not divide $a-1$, then $[a] \ne [1]$. Since $p$ is prime, the order of $[a]$ in $G$ is $p$. The order of an element of a finite group divides the order of the group, so $p \mid q - 1$, so $q = h p + 1$ for some $h$, and since $1, p, q$ are odd, $h$ must be even.

Answer (score 0):

$q$ divides $a^p-1$ can be written $a^p\equiv 1\pmod q$. Little Fermat's theroem states that $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod q$ provided that $a$ is not a multiple of $q$ (and certainly it is not).

Then $q-1$ is a multiple of the multiplicative order of $a$ in $\Bbb Z_q^\times$, which must be $p$ or $1$ since $p$ is prime. That is:

- If that order is $p$ then $q-1$ must be a multiple of $p$ and also of $2p$ because $q-1$ is even.
- If the order is $1$ then $a\equiv 1\pmod q$.

Comment: I hadn't read Caranti's answer before posting mine. Both are very similar, but notation and other details are somewhat different. I'll leave it undeleted for the moment.

Comment: Both statements are hard to me :( because I didnt learn G,this type was skipped.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120613/need-help-with-this-primitive-roots-question

Comment: In the link, The lastest answer simply say q=2kp+1 but I dont understand